# Can some know how to customize blazor components of matblazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to customize the input field textbox height more minimal and its font style. I used matblazor component to my project. Can someone know how I can solve this problem from root CSS or something like that?

Comment: I can customize RadZen components from root CSS by doing this (@import URL('_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css') in site.css but I can't find matBlazor root CSS path location in my project. Need to customize origin CSS of this matBlazor, so that I can change one place, actually, I do not want to use Style=" blah....." .

Comment: @daniherrera One should really avoid using inline CSS as it bloats the page and you can't use CSS rules to override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just include an additional CSS file in the `_Host.cshtml` like

```
...
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-custom-matblazor-styles.css" />
</head>
```

or in your `.razor` file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-custom-matblazor-styles.css" />
```

to override the CSS rules of MatBlazor.

I would favor the latter as you need the CSS file only when you are actually using a MatBlazor component on a page.

Do not mangle with the original CSS files as it will result in a complete chaos when a new version of MatBlazor is released.

Comment: Thanks, bro....
href="my-custom-matblazor-styles.css"  this line is precious !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I tried that. My CSS is very simple: ".mdc-text-field .mdc-line-ripple {
    background-color: #005f9e;
    background-color: var(--mdc-theme-primary, #005f9e)
}" ... But totally ignores my attempt to override the color.

Comment: @AurelienB might be a priority issue, try adding !important or have a look at the browser developer console to find the styles that overrides it.